# I have an error in react native with expo: "syntax error unexpected token" error. Any help to solve it? Thanks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to add brackets or semicolon, but get error:

Syntax error: Unexpected token

How I can implement this functionality and make this work correct? My full code:

Also, why is it not working?

import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Text, ActivityIndicator, View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, AppRegistry, Platform, StatusBar, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'; 
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; 
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

```
const userInfo = {username: 'admin', password: 'pass12345'} 

class HomeScreen extends Component { 
static navigationOptions = { header: null } 
constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: '', password: '' }
}

render() { 
    return ( 
        <View style={styles.container}> 
            <Text>News</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input} 
                placeholder={'Username'} 
                onChangeText={(username)=>this.setState({username})} 
                value={this.state.username} 
                autoCapitalize="none" 
            /> 
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.input} 
                placeholder={'Password'} 
                secureTextEntry={true} 
                onChangeText={(password)=>this.setState({password})} 
                value={this.state.password} 
            /> 
            <View> 
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    style={styles.btnLogin} 
                    onPress={this._login} 
                    //onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')} 
                >
                    <Text style= {styles.text}>Login</Text> 
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("Signup Works")} > 
                    <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>Signup</Text> 
                </TouchableOpacity> 
            </View> 
        </View> 
    ); 
  } 
} 

 class DetailsScreen extends Component { 
render() { 
    return ( 
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}> 
            <Text>Details Screen</Text> 
        </View> 
    ); 
} 
} 

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({ 
//Home: HomeScreen, 
Details: DetailsScreen 
}, {//initialRouteName: 'Home'} ); 

defaultNavigationOptions:{
    headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor: '#1e90ff'
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        textAlign:'center',
        flex: 1
        }
     }
},
};



const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({Home: HomeScreen});

class AuthLoadingScreen extends Component {
constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this._loadData();
}

render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <ActivityIndicator/>
            <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>
        </View>    
    );
}
_loadData = async() => {
    const isLogged = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
    this.prop.navigation.navigate(isLoggedIn !== '1'? 'Auth':'App');
}
}


export default createAppContainer(
createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: RootStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
)
);

_login = async() => { 
    if (userInfo.username === this.state.username && userInfo.password === this.state.password) { 
        //alert('Logged In'); 
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', '1'); 
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Details') 
    } else { 
        alert('Username or Password is incorrect.'); 
    } 
 } 


const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
container:{ flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#00bfff', }, 
btnLogin: { flex: 0.5, height: 45, borderRadius: 25, fontSize: 16, justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 20 }, 
btnTxt:{ }, 
input:{ justifyContent: 'center', width:"90%", padding: 15, marginBottom: 10 } 
});
```

[Expo Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZjJM.jpg)

Comment: The image attached is expo error

Comment: Fix your formatting and/or use an IDE like PhpStorm/IntelliJ. It points out the error immediately.

Comment: I see the error thank you, but how do I fix it? @mpen

Comment: Someone already answered you. Just fix your mismatching braces.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance this seems like a problem:

```js
}, {//initialRouteName: 'Home'} );
```

You've commented out the closing `}` and closing `)`.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I fix it?

Comment: Move the closing brace and paren to the next line so it's not commented out? Or use a block comment to disable just the initialRouteName part?